# Convert Date String to Int Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to convert the string:

```
let time = "7:30"
```

to integers:

```
let hour : Int = 7
let minutes : Int = 30
```

I am currently looping through the string:

```
for char in time.characters {
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to convert a char to an int. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers by @alex_p and @mixel are correct, but it's also possible to do it with Swift `split` function:

```
let time = "7:30"
let components = time.characters.split { $0 == ":" } .map { (x) -> Int in return Int(String(x))! }

let hours = components[0]
let minutes = components[1]
```

Comment: This seems to be the more "Swift-like" answer.

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Thank you!!

Comment: nice solution !

Comment: Simple and elegant!   I added    let seconds = components[2]    for my seconds needed in my project.

Answer (score 5):

Use `String.componentsSeparatedByString` to split `time` string to parts:

```
import Foundation

let time = "7:30"
let timeParts = time.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

if timeParts.count == 2 {
    if let hour = Int(timeParts[0]),
        let minute = Int(timeParts[1]) {
            // use hour and minute
    }
}
```

If you do not want to `import Foundation` you can split time string to parts with:

```
let timeParts = time.characters.split(":").map(String.init)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split string by `:` character and then convert results to Int:

```
let timeStringArray = time.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
if timeStringArray.count == 2 {
   hour = timeStringArray[0].toInt
   minutes = timeStringArray[1].toInt()
}
```